# Best way to test enqueueUniqueWork and cancelUniqueWork WorkManager

Tags: kotlin, testing, junit, mockito

What is the best way to test the methods `enqueueUniqueWork` and `cancelUniqueWork` in Kotlin in Android?
I only found answers for testing work with Id, but I have a unique name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a lot of searching, I found this tutorial:
https://medium.com/@thefallen.class/unit-testing-workmanager-with-dependencies-8ffff7ef5476

And also android documentation:
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/integration-testing

It is not possible to directly tests the methods `enqueueUniqueWork` and `cancelUniqueWork` with Mocks only.

I needed libraries such as

- `androidx.test:core`
- `androidx.work:work-testing`
- `org.robolectric:robolectric`

`androidx.work:work-testing` allowed me to initialize a Test WorkerManager thanks to the context provided by `androidx.test:core`

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)
class ClassTest{
   private lateinit classToTest: ClassToTest
   private lateinit context: Context
   
   @Before
   fun setUp(){
      context = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext()
      val config = Configuration.Builder()
            .setWorkerFactory((WorkerFactory.getDefaultWorkerFactory()))
            .setExecutor(SynchronousExecutor())
            .setMinimumLoggingLevel(Log.DEBUG)
            .build()
      WorkManagerTestInitHelper.initializeTestWorkManager(context, config)
   }
}
```

Then, I managed to get the state of my unique enqueued work and cancelled work thanks to lines such as

```
WorkManager.getInstance(context).getWorkInfosForUniqueWork("name").get()[0].state
```

Which returned elements such as `WorkInfo.State.CANCELLED` or `WorkInfo.State.ENQUEUED`

I am not 100% if this is the best method to do so, but it allowed me to test what I wanted. Hoping it could help anyone else

Answer (score 0):

Both methods came from `WorkManager` class. This class is an element of runtime environment, so testing of them is task of author of `WorkManager`.

What do you, probably, want to do is to test task executed/cancelled by those methods or test are they called.

For that second option please take a look at something called Mock. This is a special „class” that pretends your original class, but you can control how it behaves and check how it was used.